# Calculate reaction forces, bending moments and shear forces, udl=0.5kN/m

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics, moment

[image]

I have reaction forces of $R_a = 7.890625\,N$ and $R_b =1 03.359375\,N$.
My shear force calculation equates to $0\,N$ at $5.5\,m$ which I believe is correct.

However I am having trouble getting the bending moment to equal $0$ at $x=6\,m$. My calculation for the bending moment is as follows:

$(7.890625*6)-(25*5)-(15*4)-(10*2.5)-(0.5*2.5*3.75)+(103.359375*2)-(10*1.5)-(50*0.5)=-0.625$

Answer (score 1):

Well,the calculation is correct if we suppose that Ra and Rb are correct.
BUT,Ra and Rb are incorrect.The sum of Ra and Rb is equal to 110kN(you put Ra and Rb in N-correct that) but the sum of all the forces except the 0.5N/m is equal to 110KN.So,you must have forgot to put the 0.5KN/m in your shear force calculator.